# comparisonType: OrdinalIgnoreCase))' could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq

How can I correctly implement string comparison? Please see my code below. The commented code
works but I need to ignore the case.  I'm getting the error message: "comparisonType: OrdinalIgnoreCase))' could not be translated. "

```
public async Task<List<MyClass>> GetMyTaskAsync(string? str)
{   
    var myVar = await (from e in _whDbContext.PluralizedMyClass
                               //where e.MyCol == str                                  
                               where string.Equals(str,e.MyCol.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                               select e).ToListAsync();

    return myVar;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async Task<List<MyClass>> GetMyTaskAsync(string? str)
{   
    var myVar = await (from e in _whDbContext.PluralizedMyClass
                       where str == null || EF.Functions.Like(e.MyCol, str)
                       select e).ToListAsync();

    return myVar;
}
```

`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is causing the issue because Entity Framework Core (EF Core) doesn't support translating the `string.Equals`